# Where to store public images in an ASP.net MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, file

I'm quite new to the MVC Framework.

I have images I want to be able to be accessible with an absolute URL. I was told to create /images under /Content. I try to navigate to http://myapp.net/Content/images/img.jpg, and I get a 404.

Perhaps I don't know what the external URL is to get to that folder? Would there be any settings I need to set - in web.config? In IIS? (Actually, I'm running the app off VS 2013).

Comment: Obviously `myapp.net` wont work within VS. Otherwise I can confirm putting images in Content/Images should work. Have you changed the default routing scheme?

Comment: I tried it and this works if reading the image from another running web application.

Comment: You would need to turn on directory browsing in IIS.